# Printing printing variable in single quoted string Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, twitter

I am attempting to send a tweet to twitter using the twitter_oauth gem with the following code:

```
client.update('.@ #{tweeter}, have a nice day!')
```

Because of the single quotes I cannot get the variable to display but the tweet will not send if single quote are not used. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get this to work? thanks

Comment: What is the class of tweeter ? If it's a class, do you need to call a 'name'-like method on it?

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the `'` with `"`, single quoted strings don't do variable substitution and the other neat things of double quoted strings. They exist because of those missing features they are faster to parse.

If the tweet doesn't work despite using `"` then the problem is likely that the variable `tweeter` contains characters that are not allowed or in some other way invalid (maybe requiring some sort of escaping, e.g. URL or XML escaping).

Comment: +1. The difference between `'` and `"` is interpolation of variables and treatment of escaped characters. If double-quotes don't work its because of something inside the `tweeter` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the old, java-esque way:

```
client.update('.@ ' + tweeter + ', have a nice day!')
```

Or using a temporary variable:

```
message = ".@ #{tweeter}, have a nice day!"
client.update(message)
```

Comment: There is no need for a variable. Just replacing `'` with `"` does the trick.

Comment: Yup, but OP stated using double quoted method does not work. However, your comment about invalid data is probably correct.